# SharePoint Document Library Create New Document from workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, document-template

I have a document library for a weekly meeting. I want the library to automatically create a new document every Tuesday afternoon. 
How can I set this up in a workflow to look at the date and create a new document every Tuesday. 
 This document library has its own unique template. It would be great if this workflow would as set title of document to =

```
"StaffNotes.WeekOf. "&TEXT(Created-WEEKDAY(Created,3)+7,"mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could perhaps be to create a timer based Flow, where you can specify the day and time for the job to execute.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/run-scheduled-tasks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this but it requires file name and file content and I have no dynamic content showing. So I cannot create the flow.[image]